# How to Filter pandas dataframe [Error : list indices must be integers or slices, not str]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `dataframe` loaded in **colab**, my data look like this

```
id     parent_name_1    parent_name_2
1          NUll              Apricots
2          Apple             Red Apple
3          Null              Red Apple
4          Blueberries       Blueberries
5          Apple             Green Apple
...
```

this is my code

```
tm_df1 = pd.DataFrame()
tm_df1 = tm_df1.append(tm_df[type(tm_df['parent_name_1']) == 'Apple'])
```

when I want to take some of the `dataframe` and put it into new `dataframe` I get this **Error**

> TypeError-----------Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
>
> 1 tm_df1 = pd.DataFrame()
>
> ----> 2 tm_df1 = tm_df1.append(tm_df[type(tm_df['parent_name_1']) == 'Apple'])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `tm_df` is a `list` not a DataFrame? and also what is your intention with `type` , i'm not sure but unless you've overridden it, it probably doesn't do what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out the rows with parent_name_1= "Apple"

use :

```
tm_df1 = tm_df1.append(tm_df[tm_df['parent_name_1'] == 'Apple'],ignore_index=True)
```